# Is a 'Send security reports' notification on Samsung Galaxy Note 4, Android 6.0.1 legitimate?

Tags: security, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-note-4

Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (Verizon SM-N910V), Android 6.0.1.

After a sudden reboot, my phone is now displaying a new notification.

> [image]

The weird header alignment and a few typos ['Samsungs'; 'MMC(Mobile Country Code)'] put me ill at ease, and Googling this service from Samsung doesn't turn anything up.

Also, after this reboot a few details are off:

- The lock screen background changed to one of the Android defaults (I had a plain black background)
- The font reverted to the default size (I had it set to small)
- The settings buttons (screen rotation, data, etc.) in the pulldown menu changed order
- The interface seems more responsive

What does this mean? I shut off the device and am going to talk to Verizon, but I'm hoping people here might have some ideas.

My phone occasionally reboots for no reason (every couple of weeks), but I am not sure this is related. I haven't seen these symptoms before and Googling didn't turn up anything quickly.

Comment: Regarding the "Send Security Reports" itself, it seems legit ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjDMnblTM_g) to enable/disable). Regarding the reboot and settings reset... I don't have any idea, sorry.

Comment: I also found that video, but that was the only evidence I could find of that reporting feature so I didn't know whether to trust it.

Comment: What happens if you decline that ToS? I remember something similar from LG, asking me to grant them access to the device remotely – when declined, it popped up in 30min intervals. Was short of returning the device until I found out which system app to freeze to get rid of it :)

Comment: I dismissed the notification and it hasn't come back for an hour... we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go call Samsung from a different phone if you're scared to use it. I know Samsung can make screenshots and ask to send a report.